# Отрисовать один объект поверх другого через Java

Tags: java, android

Используется анимация нажатия на элемент: https://github.com/frogermcs/LikeAnimation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Могу ли я наложить отрисовываемую анимацию на кнопку? То есть, при наличии условного xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

и кода:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
```

как можно использовать класс/экземпляр класса `LikeButtonView`?

Comment: Эй, есть такой веб сервис: "Shape Shifter", советую в нем поковыряться, в их примерах. Ты и не такие анимации забабахаешь.

Comment: @Игорь спасибо за заметку) Вот этот: https://shapeshifter.design/ ?

Comment: Ага, потрать время на его изучение и будет волшебство.. Там есть ссылка на бета-проект, все тоже только с возможностью рисования своих фигур. Импорт там глючный.

Comment: @Игорь почти всё отлично, но есть маленькая проблемка. Как созданную .xml анимацию запустить над текстом в Button через Java? Вот файл с анимацией для примера: https://jsfiddle.net/egor20002012/06ajxm4p/

Comment: я более менее подробно описал в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаешь в drawable селектор

```
<animated-selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
  android:id="@+id/in"
  android:drawable="@drawable/icon_in"
  android:state_selected="false"/>

<item
  android:id="@+id/out"
  android:drawable="@drawable/icon_out"
  android:state_selected="true"/>

<transition
  android:drawable="@drawable/anim_in_to_out"
  android:fromId="@id/in"
  android:toId="@id/out"/>
```

Здесь в "item" описываешь состояние, изображение и айди. Состояний может быть не только два. Айди должны быть уникальны только для этого файла. Так же тут указывается иконка для этого состояния.

Далее в "transition" описываешь условие ее отображения, то есть переключение между итемами с указанными айди. Еще тут указан сам файл векторной анимации.

Теперь этот селектор добавляешь кнопке в поле "background" или "src", а в коде при нажатии,  в данном случае методом "Button.setSelected(true) присваиваешь ей состояние. Тогда и сработает анимация

В итоге, для кнопки тебе надо два файла-изображения и один файл-анимация.

Answer (score 1):

В xml пишите

```
<LikeButtonView
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

и находите его же в коде

```
LikeButtonView button = findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Ставите свой onClickListener и пользуетесь

Comment: Нет, вы меня не так поняли. Представьте приложение, в котором тысяча кнопок, у каждой свой id. И тут поступила необходимость запустить анимку вокруг кнопки с заданным id. То есть, решить задачу можно только кодом. Но как?

Comment: @EgorRandomize Ваша кнопка, для которой вы хотите запустить именно эту анимацию, должна быть строго LikeButtonView. Просто так воткнуть эту анимацию в обычную кнопку у вас не выйдет. Либо используйте изначально LikeButtonView, либо изучите то, как там работает эта анимация, и перенесите в нужный вам класс, благо там ничего критически сложного

Comment: Я не хочу втолкнуть анимацию в обычную кнопку, я хочу сделать вид что объекту надо рисоваться поверх существующего объекта. Костыль, но весьма изысканный